# How can I show more than 15 themes at a time in the admin menu?

Tags: themes, admin, filters, theme-options, user-interface

I have a lot of themes in my test wordpress site. I get a little frustrated that I can't show more than 15 at a time.

[Picture.png http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/5982/picturef.png](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/5982/picturef.png)

In pages and posts you can click "screen options" to choose the number, but it looks like "Themes" has no such option.

[Picture-1.jpg http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/9582/picture1bbg.jpg](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/9582/picture1bbg.jpg)

Is there another way to increase the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hardcoded into the `WP_Themes_List_Table` class that's responsible on Line 50.

```
$per_page = 15;
```

So in short, you can't without modifying a core file.

[Link to source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-themes-list-table.php).

Comment: It'll be 24 in 3.3, and perhaps someday we'll get a screen option: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19469

Comment: Didn't think to check for a ticket, thanks for adding that on.. :)